# Old missing file in wp-content/uploads/ returns a 500 error, how to catch and redirect?

Tags: redirect

I have a new site running but Google has an old PDF file indexed. The PDF file does not exist at that address on the new site, it's gone completely.

The odd thing to me is instead of the request coming back a 404, it's a 500. For example:
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/2/obsolete.pdf gives me a 500, but if I remove the dated directories I get a 404. It seems multiple missing directories in the request cause this?

Any advice or references for how a I can redirect to a 404 or the index when I get a 500 error for this type of request?

Comment: a 500 error is just a generic something went wrong, like when your favourite coffeeshop has a closed sign, nobody knows why it's closed, a 500 is just a super generic something went wrong. To find out the _actual_ error message you need to look in your PHP error log. Until you do this you won't know what the problem is. It could even be your Nginx/Apache error log you need to look into

Comment: Thanks Tom. I checked the log and see: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.` Doing some searching and this seems like it could be any number of things. I have a large multisite WP configuration and I did get the basic redirect to work on a missing file. I'm using Apache so I put the redirects into my vhost file. Still very curious and need to mess around with this on a staging env. I have 200+ sites in the live so there's that to worry about. thanks!

Comment: It might be a permission issue, try assigning a 755 or 777 to uploads directory.